# Performance tuning for intensive update scenario

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I have a "Bank Statement" collection that will handle millions of rows. The document have the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6500b6478b38cb7eb5af5ea3"),  
  "accountNumber": "CKA19587",
  "correlationId": "d22c05e6-0dcd-47e2-8f97-c7e3ef86d264",
  "transactionType": 1,
  "assetCode": "AAPL",
  "amount": 100.45,
  "settled": false
  "timestamp": 2023-04-10T19:04:39.500+00:00
}
```

Basically, each query will be filtered by `accountNumber`. The problem is that I will frequently need update the `settled` field to `true`, based on the `correlationId` field.

In short, I will first search for the document by `accountNumber` + `correlationId` and then update the field `settled`. How can I model this scenario for maximum performance and avoid bottlenecks?

Comment: Hello, you should put a compound index to optimize query.
Cf : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-compound/